# Can we set browser's proxy programatically?

Tags: c#, proxy

can we set proxy of browser programically I am talking about IE.
lets say i press a button and proxy is set and browser is opened then i press button 2 different proxy is set and new browser is opened.
here keeping in mind i want something like both opened browsers work on different proxies

like

Browser1->users->PROXY A

Browser2 ->uses->PROXY B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firefox uses it's own settings, you can set a proxy per profile, or you can use something like foxyproxy (search for the firefox addon)

Comment: sorry...wrong spot, this was in reply to Afnan's firefox question above.

Comment: so can we change that proxy by programming?

Comment: yes, you can set an override in user.js under the profile of the user/sessions you want changed, you can also edit links to firefox to launch different profiles with different proxies (or even different addons/bookmark folders/whatever)

Comment: It cut me off, check https://developer.mozilla.org/En/A_Brief_Guide_to_Mozilla_Preferences for details, prefs.js in the same folder will have existing proxy lines you can copy to user.js with whatever script you want.

Comment: Like if we we change js file and open one instance of FF it use proxy A then change again js files and open other instance first one will keep to work on proxy A because firefox needs to be restarted to get new proxy am i correct?

Comment: Indeed, user.js is applied at launch, though personally I'd still use firefox's multi-profile support. You can create a profile for your proxy settings and launch that profile instead of the default, check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options, -CreateProfile and -P are the options you'd be interested in. I guess it depends on exactly what you're doing though, as each profile has it's own bookmarks, settings, and addons as well.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. IE uses the standard WinInet proxy configuration, so whatever is configured applies to all IE instances.

It is possible though to open two different applications that host instances of the IE WebControl and configure those for different proxys.

Comment: and what about fire fox if we intend to use firefox ?i tried changing firefox proxy but it didnot got updated to ie it means firefox dose not use WinInet proxy?

Comment: I have no idea what proxy FF uses.